# Adding elements to an object in a loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, javascript-objects

I am trying to add elements to an object in a loop, but the output is unexpected.

I have tried 2 different ways that I have found on SO but neither have worked to the output I need.

```
request(options, (err, response, body) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  }
  var data = {};
  var res = JSON.parse(body);

  for (i = 0; i < res.teams.length; i++) {
    data[i] = { name: res.teams[i].name, id: res.teams[i].id };
  }
  console.log(data.name);
```

The problem with this is it outputs:
`'0': { name: 'test', id: 1 }`.
The `'0'` at the beginning is problematic.
The other way I have tried is simply:

```
request(options, (err, response, body) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  }
  var data = {};
  var res = JSON.parse(body);

  for (i = 0; i < res.teams.length; i++) {
    data += { name: res.teams[i].name, id: res.teams[i].id };
  }
  console.log(data.name);
```

The problem with this is it displays [object, Object] 20 times.

I am trying to just get an output of my object like:

```
{ { name: 'test1', id: 1 },
  { name: 'test2', id: 2 },
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to get is not a valid JS object

Comment: Sounds like you want an array of objects. In which case start with an empty array and `push` each object onto it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is an array filled with objects. What you are trying to do right now is not valid. Here's an example of the proper formatting:

```
[ { name: 'test1', id: 1 },
  { name: 'test2', id: 2 },
]
```

This is how I would refactor your code:

```
var data = [];
var res = JSON.parse(body);

for (i = 0; i < res.teams.length; i++) {
    data.push({ name: res.teams[i].name, id: res.teams[i].id });
}
console.log(data);
```

This way you will have to loop over the array to access each object, such as getting `{ name: 'test1', id: 1 }` by accessing `data[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

That would solve your problem, try this on js fiddle:

```js
  //Assuming the response body:
  // {
  //  teams: [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}],
  //    otherField: 'something here'
 // }
  var data = {};
  // Assuming response string is already parsed
  var res = {
   teams: [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}],
    otherField: 'something here'
  };

 res.teams.forEach((element, index, originalArray) => {
   data = {
    // destructuring assignment. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
   ...data,
      // Define field using braces
      ['team'+index]: element
    };
  });
  
  // Now lets show all of them. Using map() just to show you a new method
  Object.keys(data).map((element, index) => {
   console.log(data[element].name);
  });
```